# How to create a local copy from angular material

Tags: npm, angular-material

I'm working on a web app that uses Angular Material (Angular4) and they are continually updating their components (like moving from md-select to mat-select), the problem is that my web is in production, so i can't rely on the changes that they are doing because i don't need new updates on Angular Material.

I'm using npm to update the packages... My package.json looks like this
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sns4L.png)

Obs: When they make a new update the app doesn't crashes, the modules that I've imported works, but is like they are not finding the CSS so the app doesn't look really good...

Obs 2: Sorry for my english :D

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't catch up with the pace of the changes in `@angular/material` you can manually lock a version in your `package.json` file:

```
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta12"
```

When you see that a release version is finally available in npmjs, you can manually upgrade it.

---

P.S. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) explains how `^x.y.z` and `~x.y.z` work in `package.json`.